# What is causing my computer to lag?

Tags: gaming, emulation

I ripped some games from my Wii console in the hope of playing them on my PC using Dolphin Emulator. However, my PC could not even maintain 30 FPS the whole time. I have an RX 570 and an AMD Phenom II X4 CPU, but have only DDR2 RAM. When I ran task manager, both my CPU and GPU were running under 40%. Is my RAM speed the issue?

Comment: Depending on the OS involved 2gb may be the issue.

Comment: Does RAM even have a speed?

Comment: @Phoenix - Yes; Of course it does

Comment: I have 8gb, and not all of it is being used. I think that ram latency of ddr2 could be the problem. I’m using windows 10.